# Output file is getting large size than input (original) file

Tags: java, android, file-handling

I am working on reading a file and write same file, but the problem is the downloaded file is 2kb larger than input original file.

Some piece of code

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
        BufferedInputStream bis;
            ArrayList<byte[]> al =new ArrayList<byte[]>();

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.mp3");
      byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            int read ;

            int fileSize = (int) file.length();
           int readlen=1024;

                while (fileSize>0) {
                    if(fileSize<1024){
                        readlen=fileSize;
                        System.out.println("Hello.........");
                    }
                    bytes=new byte[readlen];
                    read = bis.read(bytes, 0, readlen);
                    fileSize-=read;

                    al.add(bytes);

                }

            ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/newfile.mp3"));

            for(int ii=1;ii<al.size();ii++){
                    out1.write(al.get(ii));
              //  out1.flush();
            }
            out1.close();
           File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "newfile.mp3");
```

Comment: Do not put them in an array list first. Just write the bytes to the FileOutputSteam directly in the same loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use an `ObjectOutputStream`. Just use the `FileOutputStream`, or a `BufferedOutputStream` wrapped around it.
2. The correct way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

   ```
   byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more, or even less, anything > 0
   int count;
   while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
   {
       out.write(buffer, 0, count);
   }
   out.close();
   ```

   Note that you don't need a buffer the size of the input, and you don't need to read the entire input before writing any of the output.

   Wish I had $1 for every time I've posted this.

Comment: Thanks sir , but now file is getting 1kb less than original file.

Comment: So you aren't closing `out`, or you're not using this code, or you're still using some of your own copy code as well.

Comment: sir, how to use multi-threading for splitting file.please help me i dont know more about multi threading .Thanks!!

Comment: @MANOJGAYAKWAD There is nothing in your question (or this answer) about multi-threading. If you have a new question, ask it as a new question. Not in a comment to an answer to a different question. (a) Nobody will see it there, and (b) this is a Q&A site, not a forum.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use ByteArrayOutputStream not an ObjectOutputStream.
I belive this is not a raw code, but the parts of the code, placed in different procedures, otherwise it is meaningless. 
For example, in case you want to stream some data from a file, process this data, and then write the data to another file.

```
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream al = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileOutputStream out1 = null;
    byte[] bytes;
    try {
        File file = new File("testfrom.mp3");
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        int fileSize = (int) file.length();
        int readLen = 1024;
        bytes = new byte[readLen];
        while (fileSize > 0) {
            if (fileSize < readLen) {
                readLen = fileSize;             
            }           
            bis.read(bytes, 0, readLen);
            al.write(bytes, 0, readLen);
            fileSize -= readLen;
        }
        bis.close();            
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //proceed the data from al here
    //...
    //finish to proceed

    try {
        out1 = new FileOutputStream("testto.mp3");
        al.writeTo(out1);
        out1.close();           
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Don't forget to use `try-catch` directives where it needed

http://codeinventions.blogspot.ru/2014/08/creating-file-from-bytearrayoutputstrea.html

Comment: I tried sir, but its throwing error in- ByteArrayOutputStream cannot be applied to(java.io.FileOutputStream). please can you help me how to modify this line ,because i am fresher i confused. Thanks

Comment: Why? He should use the `FileOutputStream` instead of wasting time and space on a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = getByteStreamMethod();
     try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("thefilename")) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(outputStream);
    }`

Comment: You haven't answered my question. The `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a waste of both time and space. Your new code is full of bugs too.

Comment: I assume that if a person uses an intermediate buffer is the means he needs it. For example, for processing information. I offer an answer in the context of the issue. Written code works - I checked. In the last edition I added in the code try-catch directives.

Comment: There is no evidence here that the OP actually needs the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. He just doesn't know how to write I/O code. Your own code wrongly assumes that `read()` fills the buffer. Its return value should be used as the count in the `write()` call. It also assumes that the file size fits into an integer.

Comment: I think the author should decide himself. If size didn't fits into an integer then we need to use threads to read and to proceed data by blocks - not to write all data to memory.

Comment: Whether 'size fits into an integer' has nothing to do with 'need[ing] to use threads'. Your comment doesn't make sense.\